# Why does adding an IPv6 address break IPv6 (CentOS)?

Tags: centos, networking, ipv6

I have several servers with IPv6. For some reason, on this new server, I'm having a problem. IPv6 is working until I add more addresses. Here's the output of ifconfig before adding a new IP:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1584 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 1584 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0  destination 127.0.0.1
        inet6 2001:x:x:552:f000:0:f:9999  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 27882  bytes 4994839 (4.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26536  bytes 6250120 (5.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 63 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0:0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 61.x.x.89  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 61.14.232.89  destination 61.14.232.89
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
```

Everything works but then if I add a new IP, IPv6 breaks. Here's how I'm adding an IP (I must use ip addr as my code depends on it):

```
ip -6 addr add 2001:x:x:552:f000:0:f:9ea0/112 dev venet0
```

I have also tried:

```
ip -6 addr add 2001:x:x:552:f000:0:f:9ea0/64 dev venet0
```

After I do that, IPv6 doesn't work anymore (Can't ping6 out). This server has a /112 subnet available to it. The server has CentOS 7 installed.

Comment: Can you include a command (with output) that works before you do that and not afterwards?

Comment: The same command works on other servers with /64 instead of /112. I noticed that in the initial config of this server, the default IP is added via /64  as indicated by ifconfig so I tried that as well. I have just added that information to the question but it didn't work.

Comment: Check your default route (in IPv6).

Comment: Your default route is reachable-via 2001:x:x:552:f000:0:f:9999. When you remove that address then the default route is removed from the routing table. This is why IPv6 usually has the deafult route reachable-via a IPv6 link-local address, but for some reason your interface lacks one of those.

Comment: Without further information this question is not answerable. What does `ip -6 route` output before and after the operation? Moreover, /112 is not a valid subnet for global unicast addresses. Don't try to save space - always specify subnets as /64!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was due to a virtualization platform being used that would have required me to provision each IPv6 address I need individually in SolusVM CP. I switched to a KVM-based VPS and now I have the entire subnet available to me from the perspective of the VPS.